# How to check same value of one column is present in other column multiple times or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server with table name = Immerse which contains below records:

```
ProjID  |   GroupId
--------+--------------------------
  1     |    AAA
  2     |    BBB
  3     |    AAA
  4     |    CCC
  4     |    CCC
  4     |    CCC
```

and I would like to know whether same GroupID is associated with multiple ProjID are not? and display the count

Output would be

```
GroupId  | Count
---------+-------
 AAA     |    2
 BBB     |    1
 CCC     |    1
```

Note: Here GId = 'CCC' is associated to only 1 ProjId i.e; '4' so count should be equal to 1 only

and I have written query like this:

```
SELECT
    GId, COUNT(GId) AS Count 
FROM
    Immerse 
GROUP BY
    GId, PId
```

which produces output as

```
GroupId  | Count
---------+---------
 AAA     |    1
 BBB     |    1
 AAA     |    1
 CCC     |    1
```

Do I need to use having clause after group by clause ?

Comment: `COUNT` the `DISTINCT` value of `ProjectID` instead of the value of `GroupID`?

Comment: Yes, and remove `PId` from the `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the distinct ProjIds, and then group by GroupId.  In other words this query only counts each GroupId+ProjId combination once, no matter how many times the combination appears.

```
   SELECT
        GroupID, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT ProjId)
    FROM
        Immerse
    GROUP BY GroupID
```

Answer (score 0):

When asking a question it's really helpful to provide the DDL and DML for your demo data:

```
DECLARE @Immerse TABLE (ProjID INT, GroupID VARCHAR(3));
INSERT INTO @Immerse (ProjID, GroupId) VALUES
(1, 'AAA'), (2, 'BBB'), (3, 'AAA'), (4, 'CCC'), (4, 'CCC'), (4, 'CCC');
```

In this case it looks like a quick self join might be the way to go:

```
SELECT i1.GroupID, COUNT(i2.GroupID) AS NumberOfProjects, STRING_AGG(i2.ProjID,', ') AS OtherProjects
  FROM @Immerse i1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Immerse i2
      ON i1.GroupID = i2.GroupID
      AND i1.ProjID <> i2.ProjID
GROUP BY i1.GroupID;
```

| GroupID | NumberOfProjects | OtherProjects |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 2 | 1, 3 |
| BBB | 0 |  |
| CCC | 0 |  |